# I want to shift the paragraph smaller to fit the small screen (phone or tablet screen)

Tags: html, css

I want to make the picture and the paragraph in the middle of the ipad screen (820x1180) with the media size code.
I don't know how to make the paragraph on top of  the picture as  well

Please help

```css
@media(max-width: 700px){ 
        #project2{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .about-right{
            width: 100%;
            
        }
        .about-text1{
            width:90%;
            margin:0;
        }
        
        .about-left img{
            flex-basis: 20%;
            width: 350px;
            margin: 20px;   
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<div id="ABOUT" class = "about-left-col1">
                        <img src="Image/project21.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "about-right-col1">
                        <div class="about-text1">
                            <h4>THE CAP LID<br><br></h4>
                            <p> <br>Let me tell you this,<br>
                                <br>. I learnt how to use the 3D 
                                printer at my school lab and bring my 3D prototype of the cap to life. </p><br>
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class = "button"> JOIN NOW </a>  
                        </div>
                        <h3> #Oct2022 #ProblemSolving #FromScratchtoEnd <br> #3Dmodeling #3Dprinting #DesignThinking </h3>
                    </div>
                </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share proper working HTML and CSS code Then will help you out quickly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do I share the HTML file here?